# How to just get the time part of Datediff (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql

Lets hope you can help.

```
SELECT 
Mpl.EmpNo,
CONCAT(Mpl.FName,' ',Mpl.SName) AS 'Name',
Ctt.TaskName AS 'Task',
Cts.TaskStart AS 'Start Time',
Cts.TaskEnd As 'End Time',
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Cts.TaskStart,Cts.TaskEnd) AS 'Task Time'
FROM CHDS_Management.dbo.People Mpl
LEFT JOIN CHDS_Common.dbo.TaskScan Cts ON Cts.EmpID = Mpl.EmpNo
LEFT JOIN CHDS_Common.dbo.TaskType Ctt ON Ctt.TaskShort = Cts.Task
```

I am trying to find out how long a task takes. The TaskStart and TaskEnd are datetime2(0) data types. I need to find the time difference between the 2 times.

So Joes task times are: 
15/06/2017 11:12:50 - 15/06/2017 12:14:56

I want to see a feed back for Task Time as:
01:02:06

(It was so simple in MySQL)

Comment: `convert(varchar(20),taskstart,108)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expression you want if you need `minute` granuality. Replace `minute` with `second` otherwise

```
select cast(dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, '2017-06-15 11:12:50', '2017-06-15  12:14:56'), 0) as time)
```

Comment: cast(dateadd(SECOND, datediff(SECOND, Cts.TaskStart, Cts.TaskEnd), 0) as time) AS 'Task Time'